# Decided I wanted to work VS Decided to work

Tags: grammar

I found this sentence in Cambridge Vocabulary In Use book but I can't understand it well. I am wondering that what the subject of decided is?

> **By my mid-twenties, I was getting a bit bored, and decided I wanted to work abroad**

and I also want to know that if it is not more reasonable to  just say **decided to work** or **wanted to work** instead of **decided I wanted to work**? and if we can't, what is the difference?

Comment: The *subject* of "decided" is the first "I".  The *object* of "decided" is the subordinate clause "[that] I wanted to work abroad".

Answer (score 2):

The subject of *decided* is *I*. I decided I wanted to work, is the more formal sentence.

The differences in *Decided to work* or *Decided I wanted to work* only has to do with *why* you decided to work. Perhaps you needed the money despite not wanting to work. You may decide to work having nothing to do with wanting to.

Comment: "Decided" appears in both versions. What is your point?

Comment: @Elliot. Could you document this difference? There is no reason as for why "decide" without "want" should be used only in order to express necessity.

Comment: 'Deciding to work' as distinct from 'Deciding what I want'. What one decides may or may not have to do with work. I am not claiming that 'want' is linked to 'decide'. One decision points to what they want while the other points to going to work.

Answer (score 1):

"Wanting to work" and "working" are not the same thing. You can want to work but not be able to, meaning that you want to work but don't work. You can also work for other reasons than because you want to - because you've been forced to or  because you need the money, or because it might lead to something you do want. Then you work but don't want to.

Someone who decides they want to work abroad might still not do so. Someone who decides to work abroad might not want to.

"Deciding" is also night me same as wanting. Deciding is to choose between two options but the will is not always involved, Someone might decide that the answer to an exam question was A rather than B, but the will is not involved.